# Why won't my alias give me get-help or -?

Tags: powershell

This is PS5.1

I have an alias called "proc" that points to a specific script on my machine that I have setup with the following command

```bsh
Set-Alias -Name proc     -Value "$sourceCodePath\deploy\Invoke-Process.ps1"           -Scope Global
```

If I do

```bsh
proc -?
```

or

```bsh
get-help proc
```

I get some kind of search output like I haven't been specific enough, when I just want the help page

```
> proc -?

Name                              Category  Module                    Synopsis 
----                              --------  ------                    --------          
proc                              Alias                               Invoke-Process.ps1
Enter-PSHostProcess               Cmdlet    Microsoft.PowerShell.Core Connects to and enters into an interactive session with a local process.  
Exit-PSHostProcess                Cmdlet    Microsoft.PowerShell.Core Closes an interactive session with a local process.                       
Get-PSHostProcessInfo             Cmdlet    Microsoft.PowerShell.Core                                                                           
etc...
```

Fine, this is Get-Help documented behaviour, so to narrow it down I try

```bsh
Get-Help -Category alias -Name proc -Full
```

and this just returns the single item again without any actual help information?

```
Name          : proc
Category      : Alias
Synopsis      : Invoke-Process.ps1
Component     :
Role          :
Functionality :
```

Anyone know why this happens and if there is anything I can do to make my alias behave as a first class powershell citizen without having to make a module or anything more heavyweight for this?

BTW this works

```bsh
& ((get-alias proc).ReferencedCommand.Source) -?
```

But that is a big context switch to do everytime I want to remind myself of the parameter options..

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically, the reason for this output is that `Get-Help` is returning help information about the ***Alias*** not the actual *file* referenced.

### Level 0 - TLDR

If you simply want to return basic script information, you need a small function in your profile script to:

1. Get the alias
2. Resolve the source script file location
3. Pass that file location information into `Get-Help`
4. Bonus: make it also an alias!

E.g.

```
Function Get-HelpAlias($alias){
    Get-Help((Get-Alias $alias).ResolvedCommand.Source)
} 

Set-Alias -Name gha -Value Get-HelpAlias

PS C:\> gha proc
Invoke-Process.ps1 [par1] [par2]
```

---

### Level 1 - Script file help

Let's break down what is going on:

When you ran:

```
Get-Help proc
```

Indeed, what you are seeing is the search results, as "proc" is not unique enough for `Get-Help` to uniquely identify what you are looking for. By specifying the category:

```
Get-Help proc -Category Alias
```

You get one result. You can see this if you picked a more "unique" Alias:

```
PS C:\> Set-Alias -Name zzzzzz -Value "$sourceCodePath\deploy\Invoke-Process.ps1" 
PS C:\> Get-Help zzzzzz

Name          : zzzzzz
Category      : Alias
Synopsis      : \deploy\Invoke-Process.ps1
Component     :
Role          :
Functionality :
```

As for what it returns, it is returning the help information about the *Alias*. You can clearly see that it's Category is an Alias, and that the information returned is the value contained in the Alias. You can see that here:

```
PS C:\Temp> Get-Alias proc

CommandType     Name                                               Version    Source
-----------     ----                                               -------    ------
Alias           proc -> \deploy\Invoke-Process.ps1
```

We can "fake" things by getting the alias, seeing what the referenced script is, and passing the script reference string into `Get-Help`:

```
Get-Help((Get-Alias proc).ResolvedCommand.Source)
```

If this is all you want to do, then you might as well add a function to your profile script (with an alias of course ;-) that does this for any script alias you want to reference like this:

```
Function Get-HelpAlias($alias){
    Get-Help((Get-Alias $alias).ResolvedCommand.Source)
} 

Set-Alias -Name gha -Value Get-HelpAlias

PS C:\> gha proc
Invoke-Process.ps1 [par1] [par2]
```

This is the level 1 TLDR, and would work if you are simply wanting your basic script information.

Now onto Level 2.

---

### Level 2 - Actual Help

If you want Help to be useful, you *actually have to write it*. In these examples we are giving `Get-Help` the hardest cases possible, where there is no help information, and it does it's best. For an alias, pointing to a script with no help information, give the alias information, as that is most useful. For a script file with no help information, give the script file information.

If we *actually* wrote help information, we get a **very** different result. The good news is that with PowerShell writing Help information is **Very Easy** and you don't have to be a "first class" PowerShell citizen to do it.

The easiest way to create help information is to write [Comment Based Help](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Core/about/about_comment_based_help). For ex. To write [Comment Based Help for a Script](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Core/about/about_comment_based_help?view=powershell-7#comment-based-help-for-a-script) at the top of your script simply add something like this:

```
<#
.SYNOPSIS
    Invoke-Process runs programs
.DESCRIPTION
    Connects to array of computers provided, and runs scripts.
#>


param (
    [string]$param1,
    [string]$param2
)
......
```

This is an easy way to add help to your script. Then your output (using the function above) looks like this:

```
PS C:\> Get-Help .\Invoke-Process.ps1

NAME
    C:\Invoke-Process.ps1

SYNOPSIS
    Invoke-Process runs programs


SYNTAX
    C:\Invoke-Process.ps1 [[-param1] <String>] [[-param2] <String>] [<CommonParameters>]


DESCRIPTION
    Connects to array of computers provided, and runs scripts.


RELATED LINKS

REMARKS
    To see the examples, type: "get-help C:\Temp\asdf.ps1 -examples".
    For more information, type: "get-help C:\Temp\asdf.ps1 -detailed".
    For technical information, type: "get-help C:\Temp\asdf.ps1 -full".
```

---

### Level 3 - Making it work like it should

What about cmdlets? what happens with for them? for example what happens if we pass the alias `gci` to `Get-Help`?

```
PS C:\> Get-Help gci

NAME
    Get-ChildItem

SYNTAX
....
```

Well that's different. That alias isn't returning the same as what happened above. It's actually working the way that I want it to. Why didn't mine do that???

This highlights the difference between *functions* and *scripts*. In the above examples, we were trying to get information about the script file. This is the lowest level of help functionality. "Normal" scripts don't take things like parameters, and they have some pretty boring information, so we offer our best effort. That's why when running `Get-Help proc` it returns search information, because the search information is more useful to you usually.

Functions and Modules are different. They are first class citizens because we have more information and actually matter. If we don't want to write a full module (not much harder than below) we can write our script to be a function. We then import it into the session (running the `. .\Invoke-Process.ps1`) to make the function available, and we get amazing help:

**Invoke-Process.ps1**

```
<#
.SYNOPSIS
    Invoke-Process runs programs
.DESCRIPTION
    Connects to array of computers provided, and runs scripts.
.PARAMETER Servers
    The array of Servers
.PARAMETER Program
    Program to run
#>
Function Invoke-Process {
    Param (
        [string[]]$Server,
        [string]$Program
    )
    ....
}
```

---

```
PS C:\> . .\Invoke-Process.ps1
PS C:\> Set-Alias proc Invoke-Process
PS C:\> Get-Help proc

NAME
    Invoke-Process

SYNOPSIS
    Invoke-Process runs programs


SYNTAX
    Invoke-Process [[-Server] <String[]>] [[-Program] <String>] [<CommonParameters>]


DESCRIPTION
    Connects to array of computers provided, and runs scripts.


RELATED LINKS

REMARKS
    To see the examples, type: "get-help Invoke-Process -examples".
    For more information, type: "get-help Invoke-Process -detailed".
    For technical information, type: "get-help Invoke-Process -full".
```

Simply adding a little bit more information gives you easily what you want/expect out of help.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed post! While I'm sure it is by design, I think that Get-Help should really help more by navigating to the target and give help about that.. if I wanted to know about the alias I would use Get-Alias